# javascript unexpected token COOKIE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

so i have this problem, i'm using a index.inc.php file to set a cookie and this is a must.

The problem of setting a cookie with server-side language is that it will not take effect on the first load. The javascript is on the template file index.tpl (Using XTemplate), the COOKIE2 and COOKIE3 are values defined on the PHP, they are cookie values, but on the first load, always empty.

```
var ligarei = getCookie('ligarei');
if(ligarei != "nao"){
    var cookie2 = {COOKIE2};
    var cookie3 = {COOKIE3};
    var timeout = cookie3 - cookie2;
    var timeout2 = 60 - timeout;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(timeout > 60){
            popthat();
        }
        else if(timeout < 60){
            setTimeout("popthat()", timeout2 * 1000);
        }

    });
}
```

The first getCookie function is ok, it doesn't matter if it's empty or null, but the problem is on the var cookie2 and cookie3, the result after compiled is:

```
var cookie = ;
```

And this is giving me a unexpected token error .

Any hints on how to solve this?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Setting a cookie with server-side languages doesn't take effect on the first load? What makes you think that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your issue is because you cant in fact change the php code to conform with a simple empty check.

```
var ligarei = getCookie('ligarei');
if(ligarei != "nao"){
    var cookie2 = {COOKIE2} + 0; // or + "" if it is a string
    var cookie3 = {COOKIE3} + 0;
    var timeout = cookie3 - cookie2;
    var timeout2 = 60 - timeout;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(timeout > 60){
            popthat();
        }
        else if(timeout < 60){
            setTimeout("popthat()", timeout2 * 1000);
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use client side JS code to read the cookie.

In your $(document).ready function, you can read the cookies from the `docmuent.cookies` object. There is an example here regrading how to do that:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Also, there are some third-party js libs that simplify this task, e.g. cookie jar:

http://cookiejar.sourceforge.net/

If you work this way, you won't need to incorporate into your code the situation in which the cookie is not set (it is actually set, but not when your server-side code is running.

Comment: Actually i could read and write cookies on the javascript document, but i really need to use the php cookie set, i have the getCookie function defined as you can see, but these cookie2 and cookie3 really need to be defined using php file. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are always strings. I think that you are just missing the quotes:

```
var cookie2 = "{COOKIE2}";
var cookie3 = "{COOKIE3}";
```

Whatever, you are using one language (PHP) to generate source code for another language (JavaScript) so you just be very careful to obey the syntax rules of the target language. In PHP, a usual trick is to use [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) to output the values. E.g.:

```
<?php
$value = 'Foo "bar"; test';
echo json_encode($value);
```

... prints a ready to use JavaScript string, quotes and all:

```
"Foo \"bar\"; test"
```

Last but not least, it doesn't really matter whether you are using a server-side language to set the cookie, as this snippet illustrates:

```
<?php

setcookie('current-time', date('H:i:s'));

?><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    alert("Cookies: " + decodeURIComponent(document.cookie));
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```